# Multiple Java versions running concurrently on Windows 7

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

The application runs on Java 1.6 version but my selenium project work on java 1.8 version. So, I want to run this project on that application. How do we set up different java versions? Is it possible ?

Comment: you can bundle one or the other to include the run-time.  Or, if running from an IDE, you can choose the path for the JDK/JRE to use.  The IDE doesn't have to use the system installed version.

Answer (score 0):

yes ofcourse you are just automating the application right. Your project has nothing to do with that application's code itself. You can put in your maven POM.xml to use java 1.8 in your project with a plugin. Or do you mean that you want to integrate your automation code inside the existing project of the application itself? Here is the plugin anyway:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
             </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to run two different versions of Java.